# Is possible to use local image into pods yaml in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

Is possible to set a local image in a kubernetes pod yml file?

This is my pod yml file, and the question is if I can use a local image to containers tag (in local, I have all files to my api project, dockerfile, etc).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: api-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      api-name: api-service
  replicas: 2
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        api-name: api-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api-service
          image: #HERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By local you mean it doesn't pull from dockerhub or any of the public registry.  Yes it's possible if you run a single node kubernetes. You will utlize the docker cache where your kubernetes/kubelet is running.

First thing is, you need to set your imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent.  Then, when you build your image, you need to point to the docker instance your kubernetes is using.

I do this mostly with minikube, so the dev iteration is faster without pushing to my registry.

Comment: And if I need use cluster and use many replica sets and some server instances, I need to follow this way right? Using dockerhub?

Comment: Yes you will need a docker registry.  Not specifically dockerhub.  You can setup your internal registry using nexus (  https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss ) or harbour (https://github.com/goharbor/harbor)

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate it... @Bal Chua

Comment: It looks like `imagePullPolicy` can be set in the YAML file, as a part of the container element, but where do you point to the Docker instance?

Comment: @Panzercrisis the kubelet will only talk to the container runtime (docker or containerd) where kubelet is running.  Maybe i didn't get your question.